# Polars count of dataframe is returned as data frame type

Tags: python-polars

```
len=df.select(pl.count())
```

As per my understanding this is returning count of dataframe as Data frame type . I tried to change it

```
len=df.select(pl.count()).item()
```

but again getting error

> ValueError: Since Expr are lazy, the truthiness of an Expr is
> ambiguous. Hint: use '&' or '|' to logically combine Expr, not
> 'and'/'or', and use 'x.is_in([y,z])' instead of 'x in [y,z]' to check
> membership.

My Aim is to get count from polar dataframe in integer format

Comment: Something like `len(df)`?

Comment: Are you looking for [`df.height`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.height.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jqurious mentioned it in the comments: you can use df.height to obtain the number of rows in the dataset.

If you are interested in both the number of rows and columns, you can use df.shape.

df.shape will return a tuple with the number of rows and number of columns

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other pl.gurus() you have several options, and which one suits your needs comes from your use case. I will try to list some options

```
# example dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": ["dogs", "cats", None],
        "c": ["play", "swim", "walk"],
    }
)
>>>
'''
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ dogs ┆ play │
│ 2   ┆ cats ┆ swim │
│ 3   ┆ null ┆ walk │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
'''
```

understand your df, it gives useful statistics, count and null count

```
df.describe()
>>>
'''
shape: (7, 4)
┌────────────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ describe   ┆ a   ┆ b    ┆ c    │
│ ---        ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str        ┆ f64 ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞════════════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ count      ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3    ┆ 3    │
│ null_count ┆ 0.0 ┆ 1    ┆ 0    │
│ mean       ┆ 2.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
│ std        ┆ 1.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
│ min        ┆ 1.0 ┆ cats ┆ play │
│ max        ┆ 3.0 ┆ dogs ┆ walk │
│ median     ┆ 2.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
└────────────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
'''
```

get dimensions right away

```
print(df.height)
>>> 3
print(df.width)
>>> 3
```

Get shape

```
df.shape
>>> (3,3)
```

If you want to focus on specific column 'a', and return it as a number you can do this

```
columns_count = df.select(
    [pl.col(i).count() for i in df.columns]
)
col_a_count = columns_count['a'].item()
print(col_a_count )
>>> 3
```

get unique values for each column (note that with polars list comphrension is very very very useful). By substituting n_unique with null_count you will get how many nulls you have for each column, then you already know what to do if you need other metrics...

```
df.select(
    [pl.col(i).n_unique() for i in df.columns]
)
>>>
'''
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32 ┆ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
'''
```

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your inputs . df.height resolves my issue. But I got to know more about other functions also.

Comment: yes I tried to help as much as I could. I hope you learned some tricks :)